# Uncaught TypeError: n is not a function d3.js. While trying to overlay us_map on google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, d3.js, map-projections

I am trying to overlay a US map with different states over google maps. I know I can use `loadGeoJson` function of Google Maps, but I want to color different states.

Here is the code I am trying. I have removed the API-Key while pasting the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<style>

html, body, #map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.stations, .stations svg {
  position: absolute;
}

.stations svg {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.stations circle {
  fill: brown;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key="></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

// Create the Google Map…



    d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alignedleft/d3-book/master/chapter_12/us-states.json", function(json) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
  zoom: 3,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.9716, 77.59),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});
    var overlay=new google.maps.OverlayView();

    overlay.onAdd=function(){
     var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
        .attr("class", "stations");

         overlay.draw = function() {
      var projection = this.getProjection();
          padding = 10;
        var path=d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

         var states = layer.append("svg")                   //svg width and height needs to be set.
         .append("g")
         .selectAll("path")
         .data(json.features)
         .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("fill","blue"); 
};
};
overlay.setMap(map);        



    });


</script>
```

I get the following error.
This error has been addressed in jquery section where apparently $ notation is the problem and has to be removed. However, I couldn't find the solution for d3.

```
d3.v3.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: n is not a function
    at http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:2:870
    at u (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1:31886)
    at Object.c [as point] (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:2:43)
    at Object.point (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:2:2392)
    at pt (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1:19817)
    at gt (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1:19916)
    at Object.Polygon (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:4:1080)
    at ht (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1:19734)
    at Object.Feature (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:4:601)
    at Object.ao.geo.stream (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:4:556)(anonymous function) @ d3.v3.min.js:2u @ d3.v3.min.js:1c @ d3.v3.min.js:2(anonymous function) @ d3.v3.min.js:2pt @ d3.v3.min.js:1gt @ d3.v3.min.js:1Polygon @ d3.v3.min.js:4ht @ d3.v3.min.js:1Feature @ d3.v3.min.js:4ao.geo.stream @ d3.v3.min.js:4n @ d3.v3.min.js:4o @ d3.v3.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ d3.v3.min.js:3Y @ d3.v3.min.js:1Co.each @ d3.v3.min.js:3Co.attr @ d3.v3.min.js:3overlay.draw @ overlay_hazard_map.html:63Jy @ overlay.js:1(anonymous function) @ js?libraries=places&key=MYKEY:112
d3.v3.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: n is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @ d3.v3.min.js:2u @ d3.v3.min.js:1c @ d3.v3.min.js:2(anonymous function) @ d3.v3.min.js:2pt @ d3.v3.min.js:1gt @ d3.v3.min.js:1Polygon @ d3.v3.min.js:4ht @ d3.v3.min.js:1Feature @ d3.v3.min.js:4ao.geo.stream @ d3.v3.min.js:4n @ d3.v3.min.js:4o @ d3.v3.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ d3.v3.min.js:3Y @ d3.v3.min.js:1Co.each @ d3.v3.min.js:3Co.attr @ d3.v3.min.js:3overlay.draw @ overlay_hazard_map.html:63Jy @ overlay.js:1_.zf.B @ js?libraries=places&key=MYKEY:112_.z.trigger @ js?libraries=places&key=.......
```

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, why do you think you can't color the states with the DataLayer? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1j18zd2c/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your error `n is not a function` has nothing to do with the jquery error you reference. They are similar because of [minification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) of the scripts.

---

To answer your question, though, a google maps projection is not the same thing as a `d3` projection.  You must translate one to the other.  It's pretty simple though:

```
var projection = this.getProjection();

var g2d3Proj = function(coor) {
  var gCoor = new google.maps.LatLng(coor[1], coor[0]),
      pCoor = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(gCoor);
  return [pCoor.x, pCoor.y];
}

var path = d3.geo.path().projection(g2d3Proj);
```

Other things I notice looking at your code:

1. You are setting your `svg` height/width to 60x20px in your CSS.  This will be too small for your map.
2. I wouldn't append the `svg` in the overlay draw.  Append it `onAdd`, so you don't keep re-appending when panning or zooming.
3. You aren't properly handling the enter/update selections, so panning the map or zooming won't redraw your overlay.
4. You are drawing US states but your map is centered near India.

Fixing all of these problems produces this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style>
  html,
  body,
  #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .stations,
  .stations svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
  }
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
  d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alignedleft/d3-book/master/chapter_12/us-states.json", function(error, json) {

    if (error) console.warn(error);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(39, -98),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });
    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    overlay.onAdd = function() {
      var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
        .attr("class", "stations");

      var svg = layer.append("svg");

      overlay.draw = function() {

        var projection = this.getProjection();
        var projection = this.getProjection();

        var g2d3Proj = function(coor) {
          var gCoor = new google.maps.LatLng(coor[1], coor[0]),
            pCoor = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(gCoor);
          return [pCoor.x, pCoor.y];
        }

        var path = d3.geo.path().projection(g2d3Proj);
        
        var states = svg
          .selectAll("path")
          .data(json.features);
        states
          .enter().append("path");
        states
          .attr("d", path)
          .attr("fill", "blue");
      };
    };
    overlay.setMap(map);
  });
</script>
```